# Giving specific values of a cell reference INSIDE lookup array parameter of MATCH function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to know column number of a particular text within an array in a sheet.Hence i used the MATCH function

```
=MATCH (lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type])
```

The **2nd Parameter** expects a **lookup_array**.Eg of a valid input: `C5:N5`

I dont want to specify "C" as the starting column of the array nor Row number 5 as the row number.I want it to be dynamic.I want to give a absolute column number & absolute row number.

Is there any way to do this.I have tried a lot in vain.

Comment: Than you can replace `C` and `5` with another formulas which will find your column and row based on your formula/requirement.

Comment: So you want the row number and starting column number to be inputs from another cell or formula?  Or do you want to search a 2D array for a value and return the row and column number?

Comment: Yes, there is way to do this.

Comment: @ManishChristian =MATCH(0,ADDRESS(U2,X2):ADDRESS(U2,20),0)-1 give syntax error

Comment: @ScottCraner I want the row number and starting column number to be inputs from another cell or formula

Comment: @harun24hr guidance much appreciated...i have tried address function ,but it gives a syntax error

Comment: Hard to help without looking at your data. Prepare some dummy data and update it in you question.

Comment: @Michel Put input and expected output and explain logic, how output is coming. May be we can then help you.

Comment: `=MATCH(0,INDEX(1:1040000,U2,X2):INDEX(1:1040000,U2,20),0)` will find `0` in your desired range.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks a ton.you may convert ur comment into ans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dynamic cell references are in A1 and B1 this should work...

```
=MATCH(0,INDIRECT(A1):INDIRECT(B1),0)
```